# Handling AppEngine outage with pending_ms during several minutes

Tags: google-app-engine

Today AppEngine went down for a while:
http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/serving/2012/10/26#ae-trust-detail-helloworld-get-latency

The result was that all requests were kept as pending, for some for as long as 24 *minutes*. Here is an excerpt from my server log. These requests are in general handled in less than 200 ms.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/ad3b58bf-9338-4cf7-aa35-a255d96aebbc/4b90815ba1c8cd2080b157a54d714ae0

My quota (8$ per day) was exploded in a matter of minutes when it previously was at around 2$ per day.

How can I prevent pending_ms to eat all my quota, even though my actual request is still responding very fast? I had the pending delay from 300 ms to Automatic. Does limiting the maximum to 10 seconds prevent that type of outbreak?

Answer (score 0):

blackjack75,

- You're right, raising the pending latency to something like 10 seconds will help reduce the number of instances started.

It looks like the long running requests tied up your instances.  When this happens, app engine spins up new instances to handle the new requests, and of course instances cost money.

- [Lowering your min and max idle instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) to smaller numbers should also help.

On your dashboard, you can look at your instance graph you to see how long the burst of instances was left idle after the request load was finished.
You can look at your typical usage to help estimate a safe max.
Lowering them can cause slowness when legitimate traffic needs to spin up a new instance, especially with bursty traffic, so you would want to adjust this to match your budget.  For comparision, on a non-production appspot having the min and max set to 1 works fine.

Besides that, [general techniques](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/managing-resources) for reducing app engine resource usage will help.  It sounds like you've gone through that already since your typical request time is low.  Enabling concurrent requests could help here if your code will handle threads correctly (no globals, etc.) and your instances have enough free memory handle multiple requests.